# How to efficiently query very long tables?

Tags: sql, database, performance, load

I have a table which contains 100's of millions of rows. The fields are:

two int fields
one datetime field
another int as primary key

I have created indexes on the primary key (I'm referring to the usual), a composite key on the two integer fields and another on the datetime field.

I which to query the table based upon joins against two fields only: the first int (not the pk field) and the datetime field. These queries will return the second int field, which is useful to me.

While the data goes back years and the table is inserted into every 10 minutes, I need to be able to query quickly any content within it.

I would like to know the most advisable method to go about building a SQL query or whether I should consider a different content engine entirely. Perhaps an XML DB or loading all content into a .NET web app to serve it faster?

Comment: Do you always run the same query, perhaps "pulling off the top" or could you select any of the rows?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problem if you set up your indexes right. You can grow your table as big as you want with little impact on performance.

Use the query plan to find out if your index is being used.